# Serializing and deserializing unknown inherited types

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I started looking at using proto-buf .Net for my serialization needs for media browser.

In the new system we have a entity framework that can be extended with plug-ins.

So, for example, we define a Media class in the core library, and then plug-ins can define subclasses such as Song.

It seems that proto-buf .Net needs to know about all sub types of our core defined base class.

So I am expected to decorate my base class with

```
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Song))]
```

But ... at that point in time I know nothing about the Song class that does not exist yet.

Is it back to the drawing board? Am I trying to do something the library is not designed for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from the author)

In the current release, it is fixed to types known to the parent. However, this is a known limitation, so there is a plan to abstract the meta-model so that it can be provided separately at runtime - broadly comparable to how you provide such information to `XmlSerializer` (it will still need a way to provide tags (the "2" above) per type).

I have started on this work, but I expect it to take a few weeks to get it fully working (the refactor will also tie into some other changes [to help compact framework](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/compact-framework-woes-revisted.html)).

So up to you... if you can wait a few weeks, I hope to have something working.

Note that you would still need some way of generating (unique, repeatable) tags for all the different sub-types - configuration, etc.

Comment: I have managed to get my current serialization implementation to support my limited needs. http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/branches/big_refactor/TestMediaBrowser/TestSerialization.cs

Comment: Later down the line when I you are done, I'll see if I port the stuff over to use protobuf.  Jeez stuff gets complex when you support inheritance chains of properties ...

Comment: With the unique tags .. could you not default to the typename if nothing is specified?

Comment: Indeed. Especially if the binary format (defined by Google) doesn't actually include inheritance! It already uses some clever tricks simply to achieve inheritance while retaining wire-compatibility...

Comment: No; they have to be integers to fit into the wire format. Or I'd need to think of an *even more clever* way of spoofing it. Plus, the type name is an implementation detail, where-as the wire-format is contract based - i.e. you can use different types (that match at the contract level).

Comment: hmmm.... I could probably do it by including (against a magic-number tag) the fqn / aqn of the type *at the parent*, and working backwards... breaks some purist rules, but doable. Maybe. I'd rather do the dynamic metadata thing, though.